# Imagick on xampp on Mac: cannot get image.so to be used

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp, imagick

having overcome all the hurdles (there were a few for me) of installing Image Magick, of installing and compiling imagick on XAMPP, I have the feeling that I am almost there but I cannot manage to have the extension working in apache.

The last things that I did were:

- downloading imagick from XAMPP with pecl
- unpacking it, editing the config.m4 file to have it find the Wand, `cd`ing to the root of the folder, running `phpize`, then `./configure`, then `make`, then `sudo make install`, which output this 
  `Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/
  Installing header files:          /usr/include/php/`
- then copying this imagick.so file to `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions`
- then restarting Apache to see that imagick didn't seem to be installed, as it wasn't mentionned in phpinfo

So after searching around, I tried also to copy imagick.so into the `no-debug-non-zts-20090626` folder, also located in the `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions` folder and in which I noticed a few `.so` files.

Restarted Apache, still no sign of imagick in the output phpinfo()

I then googled further, and found a tutorial mentioning that the php.ini file had to be edited as to be aware of the extension. So I added `extension=imagick.so` in the php.ini file (located in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc`), at the appropriate place, just right after `extension=imap.so`.
Again, restarted Apache, checked my phpinfo, no imagick.

I am quite frustrated as I got the feeling that I am soooo close to be there, but honestly I really don't know what I have to do know.
So I would be more than thankful for any advice, help or idea, what I need to do next.

Cheers

Comment: Try running php -i | grep imagi from the command line. You might be in the same situation as me. It is available from cli but not from apache??

Comment: @TonyGutierrez I'm having a similar problem to add extensions to XAMPP. Using `php -i | grep extension_name` let me know that I compiled the module with a different API than my PHP was. I'll have to look for PHP header files from my API (in my case: 20121212) and compile the extension/module again.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the PHP errror log, it might be that it requires a higher version of libfreetype.6 than your apache server is using.

If so you might be able to copy the one X11 is using to the apache dir. Don't forget to backup your current version of libfreetype.6